# How do I use mutate in dplyr to create new columns populated with 0 or 1 randomly

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr

I have a dataset and I need to run a loop in R to create a new column and for each row I need to insert randomly 0 or 1. The loop must run 10000 times. Since the number of columns are high, I am trying to name the columns dynamically. I tried some suggestions (as below) but that didn't work and I keep getting the error:

> ```
> Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
>   no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "character"
> ```

I tried the following code:

```
instrument %>%
select(contract_id,reporting_date,Exposure) -> testdb
i <- 1
while (i < 10001) {
  testdb %>% 
    as.data.frame(testdb)  %>% 
    varname <- paste0("abc.", i) %>% 
    mutate(as.numeric(!!varname) := sample(0:1, n(), replace = TRUE))
    i = i + 1
}
```

Comment: Piping into variable assignment (`... %>% varname <- paste0...`) is likely to thrown an error. There are ways to make it work, but it's simpler to use ordinary assignment at the beginning. If what you're working with is already a data frame, `setNames`/`purrr::set_names` are easily pipable ways to set variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, here I create 5 columns of random 0s and 1s and then convert to a data frame. You could then simple use `bind_cols()` to attach it.

```
> m <- matrix(sample(0:1,size = 25,replace = TRUE),5,5)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    1    1    0
> colnames(m) <- paste0("abc.",1:ncol(m))
> m
     abc.1 abc.2 abc.3 abc.4 abc.5
[1,]     1     0     0     1     1
[2,]     1     0     0     0     0
[3,]     0     1     1     1     0
[4,]     0     1     0     0     1
[5,]     0     0     1     1     0
> df <- as.data.frame(m)
> df
  abc.1 abc.2 abc.3 abc.4 abc.5
1     1     0     0     1     1
2     1     0     0     0     0
3     0     1     1     1     0
4     0     1     0     0     1
5     0     0     1     1     0
```